# Select max value within other select statement and display also a relevant field from the nested select

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a problem to express the next statement on mySql to return true results:

```
     select max(alltaken)mn, b.title from 
     (select  count(bc.taken) as alltaken, b.title
     from books_clients bc
     join books b on b.book_id = bc.book_id
     group by b.title) as mn
     join books b on b.title = mn.title
```

I need to return from the first select the count of the taken books grouped by title and in the external select to select the max number but also to display the corresponding title of the book. Written like this the statement returns the max number and the title grouped by b.title, values which are not related...

The following part of the statement returns only the max number, but I cannot transform it to return the title too :( :

```
    select max(alltaken)mn
    (select  count(bc.taken) as alltaken, b.title
    from books_clients bc
    join books b on b.book_id = bc.book_id
    group by b.title) as mn
```

Could you please help me to create the true query for my purpose.

Comment: Do you mean minimum or maximum? Your question contradicts itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need a subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(bc.taken) AS mn
     , b.title
FROM books_clients AS bc
  JOIN books b 
    ON b.book_id = bc.book_id
GROUP BY b.title
ORDER BY mn DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If there are more than one results with same Max count, then you need a subquery:

```
SELECT allb.mn
     , allb.title
FROM 
    ( SELECT COUNT(bc.taken) AS mn
      FROM books_clients AS bc
        JOIN books b 
          ON b.book_id = bc.book_id
      GROUP BY b.title
      ORDER BY mn DESC
      LIMIT 1
    ) AS maxb
  JOIN
    ( SELECT COUNT(bc.taken) AS mn
           , b.title
      FROM books_clients AS bc
        JOIN books b 
          ON b.book_id = bc.book_id
      GROUP BY b.title
    ) AS allb
    ON allb.mn = maxb.man
```

Comment: Thank you, it is really much more simple :) so if i want the min value I just change the order by statement to asc :) but what should I do if there is more than one result which are min or max? Thank you

Comment: Wow, its a little bit complicated but works perfectly! Thank you very much:)

Comment: @amethyst: It won't be very efficient either, with big tables, as it has to do the same operation twice.

Answer (score 1):

You can access to "b.title" in your main select as "mn.title".

I can check the validity of your SQL sentence because I don't know your database structure. If previous suggestion doesn't works you can publish your database structure so I can check it and give you the exact SQL sentence.

Comment: Hello Leticia, I have tried with mn.title but the result is the same :(. The issue is that with mn..title takes the first title from the group by statement, not the corresponding to the title which is taken max times...

Comment: Hello, try this instead in your inside query: (select count(bc.taken) as alltaken, b.title from books_clients bc join books b on b.book_id = bc.book_id group by b.title order by count(bc.taken) DESC limit 1) ... then you can use in select: select mn.alltaken, mn.title

Comment: Thank you, in fact your select is sufficient without the external one otherwise if we use both selects the result is not correct.